# Android "The payment method has been declined" for every payment method

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

I'm trying to implement in-app billing using Android, but I'm getting a weird error and I can't find anyone online with a similar problem.

I've done the following:

- Uploaded APK with billing permission to developer console as alpha
  build.
- Added Google group to test, with my personal gmail account as
  a member.
- Gone to the opt in URL and become a tester.
- Added my personal gmail account as an account enabled for testing (in settings > account details).
- Created a non-consumable product and set it to "active".
- Waited 24 hours.
- Put a signed release build on my phone.

When I press the "Buy" button, it opens the store dialog, which says "This is a test order, you will not be charged". All seems good so far, but every payment method says "This payment method has been declined." so I'm unable to continue. This includes Google Play balance, Amex card, Visa and PayPal account.

I've tried the following, none of them worked:

- Used a different google account for test payments.
- Removed my account from the list of test accounts in the developer console settings to try and use with "real" transactions.
- Tried a different device.
- Tried creating a different product.

Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

Comment: You have tried all the right things. Do you have a physical business address set in your Google Play developer console settings? Google now require all applications with in-app purchases to set a physical address.

Comment: Hi BrentM - thanks for confirming I'm not going crazy! Yes I've added a physical address. Saw the warning in the developer console and fixed that before I started testing.

Comment: Looks like this is definitely something to do with the Google developer/merchant account. The experience above was with my customer's Google developer account (I don't have access to their Google Wallet). I've created another app with the same code and published it to alpha using *my* developer account - I no longer see the "payment method declined" error and I can continue. I will contact my customer to see if they can identify any issues with their merchant and/or developer accounts.

Comment: I have the exact same issue! Any updates on this?

Comment: Customer has submitted a support ticket to Google. Hopefully they'll be able to help.

Comment: I am also facing the same exact problem. I have not found any solutions yet! What about you guys? any solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google support have advised that the error is caused because the merchant account is "under review". They're looking into the reasons for the review and attempting to resolve the issue. I'll update this answer with their final response.

The best advice is to contact Google support through the merchant help centre: https://support.google.com/merchants

**Update**: Google fixed the account and it started working straight away. You definitely need to contact them to get this sorted.

Comment: "Help" button here: https://wallet.google.com/merchant is a fasttrack for that - you can get instant help there no matter the time (via chat, phone and email)

Comment: I have the same issue with them now, how long did it take them to get it to work for you?